# Making an EnvoyFilter that can extend the timeout of outbound calls

Tags: istio, envoyproxy

I am using JMeter to load test my service.  But a lot of my calls are returning a 504 (Gateway Timout).  Researching this has shown that Envoy has a default of 15 seconds for a time out for egress calls.  (Meaning calls my service makes to other services.)

In an attempt to extend this timeout I am trying to add an `EnvoyFilter`.  I found an example of one here:  https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/16915#issuecomment-760892724

But it uses syntax that is no longer supported.  I have tried to update it to the latest syntax, but it is not working.  And when it is active, I cannot load the swagger docs for the service.

Here is my current attempt:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: EnvoyFilter
metadata:
  name: istio-outbound-traffic-timeout
  namespace: devunstable-framework-logging
spec:
  workloadSelector:
    labels:
      app: logging-service-devunstable-team1
  configPatches:
  - applyTo: HTTP_FILTER
    match:
      context: SIDECAR_OUTBOUND
    patch:
      operation: INSERT_BEFORE
      value:
        name: envoy.lua
        typed_config:
          '@type': type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.http.lua.v3.Lua
          inlineCode: |
            function envoy_on_request(request_handle)
                request_handle:headers():add("x-envoy-upstream-rq-timeout-ms", "600000")
            end
```

If there is an Envoy expert out there who can help me figure out how to add this header to my outbound (egress) requests, I would be grateful.